# Safari tabs, NSPOSIXErrorDomain:24 and file descriptors

Tags: macos, macbook, safari, macos-bigsur, file-descriptors

I have a serious problem with file descriptors and I have tried everything.

My laptop: MacBook Pro 13" 2018 with touchbar, i5, 16 Gb RAM, 512SSD. MacOS 11.3.1.

Recently Chrome just starts to crash without errors. I try to use Safari instead and have another problem.
When I open a new tab I get the following error: [safari error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJkwT.jpg)

**NSPosixErrorDomain:24** - Error: "Too many open files in system". Sorry for screenshot in russian :)

Also, javascript in browsers (Chrome and Safari) is often very slow. On some sites UI is lagging and slow, but maybe this is another problem.

To fix errors with file descriptors I changed some limits.

Default setting:

```
launchctl limit
cpu         unlimited      unlimited
filesize    unlimited      unlimited
data        unlimited      unlimited
stack       8388608        67104768
core        0              unlimited
rss         unlimited      unlimited
memlock     unlimited      unlimited
maxproc     2784           4176
maxfiles    256            10240
```

Custom settings which I tried:

```
launchctl limit
cpu         unlimited      unlimited
filesize    unlimited      unlimited
data        unlimited      unlimited
stack       8388608        67104768
core        0              unlimited
rss         unlimited      unlimited
memlock     unlimited      unlimited
maxproc     2784           4176
maxfiles    10240          10240
```

Also I checked SSD:

```
    smartctl -a disk0s2
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [Darwin 20.4.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       APPLE SSD AP0512M
Serial Number:                      C02829300TNJJ5910
Firmware Version:                   1161.100
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x106b
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       <1.2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Local Time is:                      Tue May 25 11:31:13 2021 MSK
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0004):   Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x0004):     DS_Mngmt
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         256 Pages

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     0.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        38 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          99%
Percentage Used:                    7%
Data Units Read:                    202 068 806 [103 TB]
Data Units Written:                 163 348 342 [83,6 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 2 319 293 376
Host Write Commands:                1 196 921 469
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       141
Power On Hours:                     1 308
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   46
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0

Read 1 entries from Error Information Log failed: GetLogPage failed: system=0x38, sub=0x0, code=745
```

I even tried to "light" reset macOS (without erase users data). It didn't help. From time to time I encounter crashes of various applications (browsers, Facetime, notification center, messages, Finder, etc.)

Finally, I can't understand, Mac OS can't manage with 40 tabs and several applications (Skype, Word, Outlook, Postman, vs code, archi, etc. ? My previous MacBook Air 2012 didn't have any problem...

Comment: Are you running an ad-blocker? tbh, I'm not seeing the relationship between a connectivity error & an open file error. Is that the literal translation of the error message?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have ublock origin as Chrome Plugin, that's all. Literal translation: Safari cannot open the page
Safari cannot open the page. Error: "The operation could not be completed. Too many files are open" (NSPOSIXErrorDomain: 24).
I looked for an error by error code, but no one really complained about it